# Why is mscorsvw.exe maxing out my CPU?

Tags: .net, cpu-usage

I installed my .NET windows service and right after installing I noticed mscorsvw.exe maxing out my CPU; this happens when I do a new install of my service.

Why is mscorsvw "interfering" with my windows service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What is mscorsvw.exe and why is it eating up my CPU? What is this new CLR Optimization Service?](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidnotario/archive/2005/04/27/412838.aspx)